# Block of code running in iPhone simulator and not on iPhone 4? (COCOS2D)

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I am using the ccTouchBegan and ccTouchEnded, and for some reason there is a block of code that runs perfectly on iPhone simulator and doesn't run at all on iPhone 4. This is what my methods look like:

```
-(BOOL)ccTouchBegan:(UITouch*)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

firstTouch = [self convertTouchToNodeSpace:touch];

if (!self.currentFootball.footballHasEmbarked) {

    //arrow.position = ccp(fPos.x, fPos.y);
    float newAnc = (120 + (self.currentFootball.contentSize.width * .5f) + (arrow.contentSize.width * .5f)) / arrow.contentSize.width;
    arrow.anchorPoint = ccp(-newAnc, .5);//self.currentFootball.position;
    arrow.position = self.currentFootball.position;//ccp(fPos.x-120, fPos.y);
arrow.rotation = 180;
arrow.visible = YES;
arrow.scale = 0.5f;

    //powerLevel.position = fPos;
    powerLevel.position = self.currentFootball.position;
    powerLevel.rotation = 180;
powerLevel.percentage = 0;
powerLevel.visible = YES;

    outLine.position = self.currentFootball.position;
    outLine.rotation = 180;
    outLine.visible = YES;

    CCProgressFromTo *powerBarGoUp = [CCProgressFromTo actionWithDuration:1.0f from:0.0f to:100.0f];

    CCProgressFromTo *powerBarGoDown = [CCProgressFromTo actionWithDuration:1.0f from:100.0f to:0.0f];

    id action = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:[CCSequence actions:powerBarGoUp, powerBarGoDown,  nil]];
    [powerLevel runAction:action];

    return YES;
}
else {
    return NO;
}
```

}

```
-(void) ccTouchEnded:(UITouch*)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

const float max = 100;

CGPoint endTouch = [self convertTouchToNodeSpace:touch];

if (endTouch.x > firstTouch.x) {
endTouch = ccp(firstTouch.x, endTouch.y);
    //CCLOG(@"I ran");
}

arrow.visible = NO;
powerLevel.visible = NO;
    outLine.visible = NO;
self.currentFootball.footballHasEmbarked = YES;
self.currentFootball.spiraling = YES;

if (self.currentFootball) {

    [smgr addBody:self.currentFootball.body];

}

 if (CGPointEqualToPoint(endTouch, firstTouch)) {
    CCLOG(@" I have run");
    float   anchorPointDist = ccpLength(endTouch);

    float   distFactor = distFromFb + anchorPointDist;

    projectionAnchorPoint = ccp(firstTouch.x + distFactor,firstTouch.y);

}

    CGPoint diff = ccpSub(endTouch, projectionAnchorPoint);

    float len = powerLevel.percentage;

CGPoint norm = ccpNormalize(diff);

if (len > max){
    len = max;
}

[self.currentFootball applyImpulse:ccpMult(norm, (len * 300))];

pos = self.currentFootball.position.y;

[self schedule:@selector(newFootball)];
```

}

This is the block of code that will not run on my iPhone.

```
if (CGPointEqualToPoint(endTouch, firstTouch)) {
    CCLOG(@" I have run");
    float   anchorPointDist = ccpLength(endTouch);

    float   distFactor = distFromFb + anchorPointDist;

    projectionAnchorPoint = ccp(firstTouch.x + distFactor,firstTouch.y);

}
```

Am I not doing something right?

Comment: could you explain what are you trying to do? what kind of gesture are you handling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Print out the values for endTouch and firstTouch. They may vary by a very small amount on device, as it's harder to keep your finger in the same location as opposed to a mouse pointer. If that's the case, you may want to accept end touches within a range of the first touch.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps there is some slight difference in the points you are comparing, making the result of that comparison always false. Try using this method instead of CGPointEqualToPoint.

```
BOOL ccpFuzzyEqual(CGPoint a, CGPoint b, float variance);
```

Comment: How much variation does ccpFuzzyEqual allow?

Comment: Sorry, should have looked at ccpFuzzyEqual a little closer. thanks for the help.